# How to add title and axes to subplot animations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm generating 4 animations in the same plot. I would like to put a title and specify the name of the axes of each one separately. How can I do this?

The code for the plot is below

```
# AnimationEvolution of perturbation equations

N_plots = int(nt/nsave)

fig, ((axF, axS), (axH, axHamilt)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

graphF,=axF.plot([],[])
graphS,=axS.plot([],[])
graphH,=axH.plot([],[])
graphHamilt,= axHamilt.plot([],[])
axF.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
axF.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axF.grid()
axS.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
axS.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axS.grid()
axH.set_ylim(-0.3, 0.3)
axH.set_xlim(ri, 1.1*radius)
axH.grid()
axHamilt.set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
axHamilt.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axHamilt.grid()
def animate(i):
  graphF.set_data(r, Fevol[i])
  graphS.set_data(r, Sevol[i])
  graphH.set_data(r, Hevol[i])
  graphHamilt.set_data(r, Hamiltevol[i])
  graphS.set_color("darkorange")
  graphH.set_color("forestgreen")
  graphHamilt.set_color("red")
  return graphF, graphS, graphH, graphHamilt
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N_plots, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set up axis title using this function: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html like matplotlib presented. Please try something like this:

```
# AnimationEvolution of perturbation equations

N_plots = int(nt/nsave)

fig, ((axF, axS), (axH, axHamilt)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

graphF,=axF.plot([],[])
graphS,=axS.plot([],[])
graphH,=axH.plot([],[])
graphHamilt,= axHamilt.plot([],[])
axF.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
axF.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axF.grid()
axS.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
axS.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axS.grid()
axH.set_ylim(-0.3, 0.3)
axH.set_xlim(ri, 1.1*radius)
axH.grid()
axHamilt.set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
axHamilt.set_xlim(ri, rf)
axHamilt.grid()
# Added
axHamilt.set_title('axHamilt')
axH.set_title('axH')
axF.set_title('axF')
axS.set_title('axS')

def animate(i):
  graphF.set_data(r, Fevol[i])
  graphS.set_data(r, Sevol[i])
  graphH.set_data(r, Hevol[i])
  graphHamilt.set_data(r, Hamiltevol[i])
  graphS.set_color("darkorange")
  graphH.set_color("forestgreen")
  graphHamilt.set_color("red")
  return graphF, graphS, graphH, graphHamilt
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N_plots, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

I have done some workaround in your code, but you can change the contents in the bracket and put whatever you want.
I hope it was useful.